# how to load style-sheet and java script and j query based on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

In asp.net i want to load style-sheet and java script and j query based on device (desktop, tablet, mobile).

based on device i want inter change style-sheet and java script and j query

Comment: Generally speaking - you shouldn't care about the class of the device. Care about what it can do. Deal with viewport size and with the existence of touch input, not with desktop/tablet/phone.

Answer (score 0):

Detect user-agent in your asp.net code and then load the appropriate stylesheets and scripts

```
<% if(Request.UserAgent.contains("Android"){%>

include android CSS here

<%}else{%>

include iPhone css here

<%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to detect browser agent and then call your js/css accordingly:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|AppleWebKit|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )
{
      // Call your files here.
}
```